# apache_request_headers() versus $_SERVER

Tags: php, apache

As far as I can tell, `apache_request_headers()` provides the same information as `$_SERVER`, but with slightly different keys.  Why should someone ever use `apache_request_headers()` and not just get this information from `$_SERVER`?  I am operating PHP 5.3.18 with Apache on Centos.  Thank you

EDIT.  identical data from `$_SERVER` and `apache_request_headers()`

```
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: HTTP_HOST: www.badobe.com
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: Host: www.badobe.com
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: HTTP_ACCEPT: */*
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: Accept: */*
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-US,en;q=0.5
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: HTTP_REFERER: http://www.badobe.com/demo/administrator/index.php?cid=3
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: Referer: http://www.badobe.com/demo/administrator/index.php?cid=3
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: HTTP_COOKIE: PHPSESSID=feg3ecd4rsefvd03mgg6qear21
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: Cookie: PHPSESSID=feg3ecd4rsefvd03mgg6qear21
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: Connection: keep-alive
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE: Sun, 02 Jun 2013 15:48:42 GMT
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: If-Modified-Since: Sun, 02 Jun 2013 15:48:42 GMT
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: max-age=0
Jun  2 08:50:53 localhost httpd: Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i would guess the function only works with Apache. but that is just a wild guess

furthermore i would guess the function returns ALL headers, where I think $_SERVER contains a predefined set of headers

Comment: The function is not Apache-specific (just badly named) and it returns FEWER elements than $_SERVER, which also includes other server properties.

Answer (score 7):

Because [apache_request_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) returns an associative array of all the HTTP headers in the current request, where as [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) gives more than that

- header details
- path details
- script locations

Comment: Thanks Starx.  Is there anything different or new in `apache_request_headers()` which isn't in `$_SERVER`?

Comment: Thanks again Starx.  But isn't `apache_request_headers()` redundant?  See my edited original post.  What new information does it provide?  Also, is it microscopically slower than just accessing the $_SERVER array?

Answer (score 6):

`apache_request_headers` is not (completely) portable, and `$_SERVER` is not entirely complete. Most specifically `$_SERVER` never contains any `Authorization` header, no matter if PHP could process its value internally or not.

Since 5.4.0 `apache_request_headers` was patched to also show all headers in CGI deployments.