# Ionic can't get open cors

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel, ionic-framework

I am trying to get API data from live server in ionic android app but it returns this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api/categories/' from origin 'http://192.168.43.71:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

#### Server settings

Now I am using Laravel for live server which is giving the API here is how I set CORS in my laravel application:

`/bootstrap/app.php`

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
    // rest of the file
```

due to my setup above I'm getting this result on CORS tester

[image: one]

#### Ionic settings

So I've been reading how to solve this issue and came cross lots of similar solutions and this is what I add to my `ionic.config.json` file

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api/*",
      "proxyUrl": "https://example.com/api/"
    }
  ]
```

### Get request (ionic services)

Here is how I request my get method

```
apiUrl = 'https://example.com/api/categories/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCategories(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}`).pipe(
      map(categories => categories)
    );
  }
```

**Any idea what else should I do to fix this issue?**

Comment: you should use this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: @SalmanZafar well that does the same results as i got in my screenshot isn't it?

Comment: but cors issues should be handle on server side it is better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SOLVED

Thanks to `Stephen Romero` for pointing the important part of this solution,

based on stephen answer I added this code to my function:

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
```

and used it in my get request like:

```
return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}`, httpOptions).pipe(
```

Now the for header permissions I used (installed) [this package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) for on my laravel app and made config file set as code below:

```
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'OPTIONS'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

## FOR those who doesn't use Laravel

Set your headers like this:

```
if($request_method = 'GET'){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Expires, Pragma, DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range');
    header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *");
}
```

The most important part of this headers is `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` part, if you simply use `*` it won't work! you need to set headers name.

Hope it helps.

## Update

Forgot to mention in order to avoid error `301` you need to remove `/` from end of your api url.

```
// my api (before)
https://example.com/api/categories/

//changed to
https://example.com/api/categories
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue using these Headers for my API:

```js
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");
```

And Angular Http:

```js
//GET data details
 getData(authToken){
      const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
              'Content-Type':  'application/json',
              'Authorization': authToken
            })
   };
   //console.log(authToken);
   return this.http.get(this.apiGetUrl, httpOptions).retry(3);
 }
```

Like the previous answer, an Options request automatically gets sent with the GET or POST. If you have apache servers, you can echo`$headers = apache_request_headers();` to see what is all coming through. Comparison for `$_SERVER and Apache` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884518/apache-request-headers-versus-server).

In my case, I run if statements:

```js
if(isset($headers["Authorization"]) && isset($headers["Content-Type"])){
  //handle get request
  }
else{
  //handle options request
   echo " False,Re-routing Options Request";
  }
```

I would test your HTTP call in the browser and look at dev tools to confirm the requests being sent. I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks man, I upvoted your answer because i needed part of it, but it wasn't full solution so i'm gonna share it myself. <3

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps at some point a preflight OPTIONS request is done by the client and since it isn't a listed method in your Access-Control-Allow-Methods it ends up in a CORS issue.

You should try to make a request to your server endpoint with OPTIONS method to check if this is the case, you can use POSTMAN to make this test.

Then try to add the OPTIONS method to the Access-Control-Allow-Methods and check the difference.

Comment: in postman it returns data just fine without set any headers, also i changed my methods from get to *

Comment: Yeah right because postman is not a browser, you can try to add the OPTIONS to your Access-Control-Allow-Methods and see if there are any differences in your app

Comment: I did unfortunately there is no difference